# CherryPy + Apache2 - Response cached

Tags: python, apache, mod-python, cherrypy

I'm trying to develop a **CherryPy based system**.
I'm actually using **Apache2** web server + **mod_python**.
I have the next problem:

When I update the code of my cherrypy app, **refresh** several times the browser, and **the result is the same as before editing**.
It seems to be caching the response somewhere.
When I restart the Apache server, the problem is solved, but refreshing the browser without restarting apache allways return the same response despite updating the source code of my app.

**How can I get the last version of my CherryPy app without having to restart the web server each time I make an edition on it?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why aren't you using `mod_wsgi`?

Comment: "Can someone explain me?"  Step 1.  Search Stack Overflow for the answer to your question.  Step 2.  Search Google for the answer to your question.  Step 3.  Think.  Step 4. If you still have questions, ask a **new** question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not from the cherrypy docs (but from [Django's Running a development server with mod_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#running-a-development-server-with-mod-python)), but maybe it helps:

> Just set `MaxRequestsPerChild 1` in your httpd.conf file to force Apache to reload everything for each request.